# Get Access to Sharepoint site using sharepy

Tags: python-3.x, sharepoint

I am trying to connect to a sharepoint site, however I get the AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'.

my code is as follows

```
import sharepy
s = sharepy.connect("https://example.sharepoint.com/",\
                username='username', password='password')
```

Any idea why I get this error? I am allowed in the site, but not on the https://example.sharepoint.com/ server url, and also not allowed through python. I have tried several other ways in, using urllib.request and also requests. There my issue lies with having the HTTPError: Forbidden. The code run there is:

```
from sharepoint import SharePointSite, basic_auth_opener
server_url = 'https://example.sharepoint.com/'
opener = basic_auth_opener(server_url, "username", 
"password")
site = SharePointSite(server_url, opener)

for sp_lists in site.lists:
   print(sp_lists.id)
```

Seems like I have an issue with permission on the server or could it be something different?

Answer (score 3):

`sharepy` shows this error if SharePoint returns an error message during the authentication. It is an error in the library because it doesn't know how to handle all error codes.

In your case the site url is wrong - `"https://example.sharepoint.com"` instead of `"https://example.sharepoint.com/"`.

Answer (score 0):

it might possible that you are missing header or other, please follow below link for more ideas on **HTTP Error 403: Forbidden**

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204644980/why-am-i-seeing-a-403-forbidden-error-message