# Accessing SharePoint via Python Office 365 SSL Error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, sharepoint, office365, attributeerror, sharepoint-api

Code worked completely fine and out of nowhere started giving me this error message: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Only other issues I can find online are for the Sharepy libary [here on Github](https://github.com/JonathanHolvey/sharepy/issues/20) and [here on Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54020081/get-access-to-sharepoint-site-using-sharepy)

Not sure what else can be tested on my end or what the Systems Admin can do to resolve this issue. If I could better target where to troubleshoot (login credentials, code to access, etc) that would be optimal.

The Systems Admin and I have tried using new credentials with no success, and I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the library, and testing on a new Python Environment, to no success.

Code used in script:
`from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext`
`from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential`

`client_credentials = ClientCredential(client_id,client_secret)`
`ctx = ClientContext(sitepath).with_credentials(client_credentials)`

`web = ctx.web`
`ctx.load(web)`
`ctx.execute_query()`

The last line is where the error is thrown when I run it line by line.

Full error code:
SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\restoffilepath\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
702             # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 703             httplib_response = self._make_request(
704                 conn,

c:\Users\restoffilepath\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
385         try:
--> 386             self._validate_conn(conn)
387         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

c:\Users\restoffilepath\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
1039         if not getattr(conn, "sock", None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
-> 1040             conn.connect()
1041

c:\Users\restoffilepath\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in connect(self)
415
--> 416         self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
417             sock=conn,

c:\Users\restoffilepath\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs, server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir, key_password, ca_cert_data, tls_in_tls)
448     if send_sni:
--> 449         ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
...
---> 45             self.error = e.response.text
46             raise ValueError(e.response.text)
47

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: [Link to GitHub issue](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/issues/661) here there is information and feedback from the Repo Owner. No fix or workaround has yet to be found.

Comment: I had a similar issue with another library that required changing pythons SSL security level. I'd be surprised here though, as nothing has changed on the client end.